# How to create parameter in ARM of Azure Data Factory?

Tags: azure-data-factory

I need Azure DevOps CI/CD Tips.

I have Azure Data Factory which has Web Activity to Post json to Azure LogicApps. (ADF Web->Logic Apps) I have made URL as parameter in Web Activity.

How to make URL as parameter in ARM?

Is Manage->ARM Template->Edit Parameter Configuration correct place?
What code should modified added?

Comment: Also checkout [Use custom parameters with the Resource Manager template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/continuous-integration-delivery-resource-manager-custom-parameters)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **Global Parameter** for the `URL` and *select* **Include in ARM template** option.

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Added globalParameters, checked include in ARM and saved, but cannot see in parameter json file in Git.

Comment: When you publish a factory or export an ARM template with global parameters, a folder called globalParameters is created with a file called your-factory-name_GlobalParameters.json. This file is a JSON object that contains each global parameter type and value in the published factory.   Checkout: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/author-global-parameters#cicd

Comment: I found the file. Thanks!